# Joining to parent table in CakePHP Model->find()

Tags: sql, cakephp, join, model, find

I have a hierarchy of CakePHP models that looks like:

`Users > Feedfolders > Feeds > Entries`

From within the FeedsController, I'm trying to get a count of all unread Entries based on user ID grouped by feed ID.  I'm really at a loss as to how I should be doing this in a way that fits within Cake's way of doing things.  I feel like Cake's understanding of the models based on the `$belongsTo` and `$hasMany` properties in the models should let it resolve the joins appropriately, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I've tried several `find()` variations with no success.  Most recently I tried:

```
$result = $this->Feed->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id'), 'Entry.read' => 1),
  'fields' => array('count(Entry.feed_id) as Count', 'Entry.feed_id'),
  'group' => 'Entry.feed_id',
  'recursive' => 2)
);
```

Which generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT count(`Entry`.`feed_id`) as Count, `Entry`.`feed_id`, `Feed`.`id`
FROM `feeds` AS `Feed`
LEFT JOIN `feedfolders` AS `Feedfolder` ON (`Feed`.`feedfolder_id` = `Feedfolder`.`id`)  
WHERE `User`.`id` = 5
AND `Entry`.`read` = 1
GROUP BY `Entry`.`feed_id`
```

Which results in the following error:

```
SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Entry.feed_id' in 'field list' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]
```

I see the problem with the SQL, and could hand write a query to do what I want, but this seems like the sort of thing that should be doable within CakePHP without resorting to hand-crafted SQL.

How should I setup my `find()` call to do what I want, and, does my plan to find unread Entries via the FeedsController make sense from an MVC standpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this from the **Feeds** controller.

```
/**
 * Bind the Feed model to the Entry model
 * and set a condition of 'read' => false
 */
$this->Feed->bindModel(array(
  'hasMany' => array(
    'Entry' => array(
      'conditions' => array(
        'Entry.read' => false
      )
    )
  )
));

/**
 * Get all the feeds and their accompanying
 * entries that belong to the current user
 */
$unread = $this->Feed->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Feedfolder.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
  )
));
```

What's happening here?

Firstly, we bind the **Feed** model using **hasMany** with the **Entry** model. At the same time, we also set up a condition *('Entry.read' => false)* that ensures that only unread messages are returned.

Secondly, we can call a find on the **Feed** model, setting the condition that the **Feedfolder** should belong to the current user.

Comment: This is 90% of the way there for what I need, and it's my fault for misstating what I actually wanted.  I need to get the count of unread entries grouped by the feed id.  Can this code be adapted to that?

Comment: @theraccoonbear - See my new answer. It's a bit long winded but it does the job. Hope it works for you. Moz

Answer (score 0):

Let's try again. This time, I'm working directly from the **Entries** controller.

```
/**
 * Unbind the existing relationship with Feed
 */
$this->Entry->unbindModel(array(
  'belongsTo' => array('Feed')
));

/**
 * Explicitly bind of the 'parent' models
 */
$this->Entry->bindModel(array(
  'hasOne' => array(
    'Feed' => array(
      'foreignKey' => false,
      'conditions' => array('Feed.id = Entry.feed_id')
    ),
    'Feedfolder' => array(
      'foreignKey' => false,
      'conditions' => array('Feedfolder.id = Feed.feedfolder_id')
    ),
    'User' => array(
      'foreignKey' => false,
      'conditions' => array('User.id = Feedfolder.user_id')
    )
  )
));

/**
 * Find the entries that are unread and belong to the current user
 * and then Group by Feed.id
 */
$unread = $this->Entry->find('all', array(
  'fields' => array(
    'Feed.Title',
    'COUNT(Entry.id) AS UnreadCount'
  ),
  'conditions' => array(
    'Entry.read' => 0,
    'User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
  ),
  'group' => array(
    'Feed.id'
  )
));
```

What's happening here?

Firstly, we unbind the **Feed** model.

Secondly, we explicitly bind the **Entry** model with **Feed**, **Feedfolder** and **User** models. This prevents Cake trying to use it's automagical goodness (which is still great btw).

Lastly, we call a find on the **Entry** model and set up our required conditions: *entries that are unread* and *belong to the current user*. We then group it all by the *Feed.id*.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
$this->Category->bindModel(
            array('belongsTo' => array(
                    'ParentCategory' => array('className' => 'Category',

 'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'),
    )));
```